# How to get latestOfMany() from a not directly related Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have

```
class People extends Model {
     public function invoices() {
          return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class)->orderBy('date', 'desc');
     }
}
...
class Invoice extends Model {
    public function person() {
          return $this->belongsTo(People::class, 'people_id');
    }
    public function latestInvoice(){
        return $this->hasOne(Invoice::class)->latestOfMany();
    }
}
...
class Clerk extends Model { 
    public function people() {
        return $this->hasMany(People::class)->orderBy('Nachname', 'desc');
    }
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the latest Invoice for a Clerk and display it in the clerk.index.blade.

I hope that is not confusing.

In other words I'm trying to find the last() or first() of a not directly related or 2nd hand relationship.

What I tried:

```
class Clerk extends Model {    
    public function lastBill(){
        $people = $this->people()->get();
        $c = collect();
        foreach($people as $person){
            $c->add($person->latestInvoice);
        }
        $c->sortBy('date');
        return $c->first()->date;
    }
}
```

^This, although it works, is totally hopeless and slow, and probably very stupid.

How do I set up my relationships properly.

Or maybe I can do a raw query with select and join?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hasOneThrough relationship:

```
class Clerk extends Model {    
    public function latestInvoice(){
      return $this->hasOneThrough(Invoice::class, People::class)->orderByDesc('date');
    }
}
```

Then, you can do something like:

```
Clerk::with('latestInvoice')->paginate();
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer. Unfortunately: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneThrough::latestOfMany()

Also It should be hasManyThrough I think. I did the following, unfortunately it's still very slow.
$this->hasManyThrough(Invoice::class, People::class)->orderBy('date')->get()->last();

Comment: I edited my answer, still using hasOneThrough but using orderByDesc('date') instead of latestOfMany()

Answer (score 0):

I only need the single most recent invoice date, so I ended up with this:

```
public function latestInvoice() {
    $invoice = $this->hasOneThrough(Invoice::class, People::class)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
    return $invoice;
}
public function latestInvoiceDate(){
    $invoice = $this->latestInvoice();
    $date = isset($invoice->date) ? $invoice->date->isoFormat('DD.MM.Y') : '';
    return $date;
}
```

sorting by id is faster than by date, and it's the same result...
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You should return an Eloquent Relationship, return $this->hasOneThrough(Invoice::class, People::class)->orderBy('id', 'desc'); And then you can use With method just like my answer below for eager loading. So, you will reduce the number of query call to database. Reference N + 1 problem here: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-n1-query-problems

Comment: I guess that is right, in the bigger context, but I really only need the most recent one, not the whole collection ordered by date, nor do I need to paginate them. So basically I'm doing the same thing, just adding ->first(), which gives me exactly the most recent one. Speed is very acceptable now, and its 185k invoices.